# Codeigniter2 - Generate a table that contain multiple sub-table

Tags: codeigniter

For the [**Table class**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html) in user guide, it mention how to generate a table with multiple columns/rows. But I want to ask how can we generate a table that contain multiple sub-table, example as below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>sub-table-01</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>sub-table-02</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>sub-table-n</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Could anyone suggest the snippet for this function?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the calls to `generate()`. Example:

```
$data1 = array(
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(4, 5, 6),
    array(7, 8, 9),
);
$data2 = array(
    array('a', 'b'),
    array('c', 'd'),
    array('e', 'f'),
);
$data3 = array(
    array('Heading1', 'Heading 2', 'Heading 3'),
    array('Row1', $this->table->generate($data1), $this->table->generate($data2)),
    array('Row2', $this->table->generate($data1), $this->table->generate($data2)),
    array('Row3', $this->table->generate($data1), $this->table->generate($data2)),
);
echo $this->table->generate($data3);
```

You'll have to replace this with your own data in a way that makes sense of course, but hopefully this gives you the idea.